# Visual Studio 2013 doesn't show local variable values during debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

My VS2013 doesn't show local variable values when I start debugging by setting a breakpoint as shown in the attached picture with red question mark. I have already checked "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" but it doesn't work for me. Please suggest what I am supposed to do.

[image: Screenshot of VS2013 Debugging using breakpoint]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot it looks like you are viewing the "Watch 1" window (used for evaluating expressions and variables). What you're looking for is called the "Locals" window. You can find it using the menus Debug -> Windows -> Locals while running the solution.